# Stop a flexbox container from growing based on children without absolute dimensions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass, flexbox, jsx

Here a the codepen of my problem:
https://codepen.io/maximilian118/pen/VwYomJv

I have a sidebar on this React component which contains a comments section.

[image]

The sidebar's height is determined by the image. The "creator" div at the top of the sidebar and the input field at the bottom both have absolute heights and I want to use flex-grow on the comments section to fill the rest of the space in between.

The problem is that as I add more children to the comments section it wraps them all and grows in height:

[image]

I would like the comments section height to remain the same without using an absolute height and to simply use overflow-y: scroll. How can this be done?

React JS:

```
<div className={`photo-card-wrapper ${imgClicked}`}>
  <div className="img-wrapper" onClick={() => imgClickedHandler()}>
    {img}
  </div>
  <div className="sidebar">
    <div className="creator">
      {profileImg}
      <div className="creator-info">
        <h5>{name}</h5>
        <p>{username}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div className="comments">
      {comments.map(comment => (
        <div className="comment">
          <img alt="Profile Image" src={require(`../../static/defaults/${comment.profileImg}`)}/>
          <p>{comment.comment}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
    <input type="text" name="comment" id="comment" placeholder="Write a comment" />
  </div>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
.photo-card-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  border: 1px solid $color-1;

  h5 {
    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  p {
    font-size: 0.7em;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: $color-2;
  }

  .img-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    width: 75%;

    img {
      width: 100%
    }
  }

  .sidebar {
    width: 25%;
    background: $white;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    justify-content: space-between;

    .creator {
      width: 100%;
      padding: 10px;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      border-bottom: 1px solid $color-1;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      cursor: pointer;

      img {
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        border-radius: 40px;
        background-image: url('../../static/defaults/placeholder.png');
        background-size: contain;
        margin-right: 10px;
        flex-shrink: 0;
      }

      .creator-info {
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: column nowrap;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
      }
    }

    .comments {
      width: 100%;
      padding: 10px;
      flex-grow: 1;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      overflow-y: scroll;

      .comment {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        display: flex;
        cursor: pointer;

        p {
          background-color: $color-1;
          border-radius: 5px;
          padding: 2px 5px;
        }

        img {
          width: 20px;
          height: 20px;
          border-radius: 20px;
          background-image: url('../../static/defaults/placeholder.png');
          background-size: contain;
          margin-right: 5px;
          flex-shrink: 0;
        }
      }
    }

    input {
      height: 35px;
      border: none;
      font-size: 0.9em;
      padding: 5px 10px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
      border-top: 1px solid $color-1;
    }
  }
}

.img-clicked {
  .img-wrapper {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: $black;
    position: fixed;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    justify-content: center;
    border-radius: 0px;
    border: none;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

    img {
      border-radius: 0px !important;
      max-width: 100vw;
      max-height: 100vh;
      object-fit: contain;
    }
  }

  .sidebar {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: Try adding this to your code: `.comments { min-height: 0 }` or `.comments { overflow: auto }`.

Comment: Unfortunately, min-height does nothing and overflow doesn't help me with changing the height of the comments section

Answer (score 0):

Adding `align-items: flex-start` on `.photo-card-wrapper` should help you. The default behavior is to stretch all items and setting it to `flex-start` would make them all stick to the top.

[More details about align-items property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items).

Comment: Wow so close! By adding `align-items: flex-start` the image is back to normal but the sidebar is still the same height. It seems the sidebar is now dictating the height of the component as it's the longest in height. I have noticed that if I add `max-height: 388px` to `.photo-card-wrapper` I get exactly what I want but of course I'm trying to avoid using abolsute heights. `max-height: 100%` unfortunately does nothing.